# Convert from `&PathBuf` to `PathBuf`

Tags: rust

This seems to be a very simple question, but I haven't got a clue from the documentation. The code creates a `PathBuf` from `&PathBuf`. I wonder what makes this possible. The documentation has an [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3C%26String%3E-for-String) that creates a `String` from `&String`, but doesn't have one such implementation for `PathBuf`? What's happening behind the scene? And what tools/methods can help me debug/investigate?

```
fn main() {
    let a = std::path::PathBuf::from("");
    let b = std::path::PathBuf::from(&a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion goes via `OsStr`.

`PathBuf` has an implementation [`impl AsRef<OsStr> for PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#impl-AsRef%3COsStr%3E-for-PathBuf) and an implementation [`impl<T: AsRef<OsStr>> From<&T> for PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#impl-From%3C%26T%3E-for-PathBuf)

Incidentally, this is how the case works for `a` as well. `PathBuf` doesn't implement `From<&str>` but `&str` does implement `AsRef<OsStr>`.

Comment: This is close. I think `Path` is not involved here because `PathBuf` goes via `OsStr` too? By the way how did you find this?

Comment: @TSK, you're right, I was looking at `Path` because I initially went down the deref route. I've updated the answer. One way of seeing is using the [hover](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#hover) feature of rust-analyzer. When you look at the `from` method, it gives the docs for the implementation it's using, in this case it says "Converts a borrowed `OsStr` to a `PathBuf`."

Comment: OK. One nit: You edited the link to `PathBuf` but not the text, which is still `Path`.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go from `&T` to owned `T` is via the [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait, and [it is implemented for `PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-for-PathBuf):

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = std::path::PathBuf::from("");
    let b = a.clone();
}
```

Comment: Would you consider `Clone` is strictly better than `ToOwned`?

Comment: And what would be your answer to the question "what tools/methods can help me debug/investigate"

Comment: I think `to_owned` is often better than `clone` as clone can sometimes leave you with borrowed data. If `struct Foo;` doesn't implement `Clone`, `let a = &Foo; let b = a.clone()` leaves `b` as a reference. It makes sense and the compiler doesn't let anything bad happen but I often find it confusing, especially when working with new libraries.